# How can I update an UpdatePanel from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Given an Asp.Net page that contains UpdatePanels.
How to update a specific UpdatePanel from the client-side.

And is it possible to update it from a dialog opened from this page? (via window.open)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some code you have already, to get an impression of the code-requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some links to take a look at...

[Easily refresh an UpdatePanel, using JavaScript](http://encosia.com/2007/07/13/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/)

[How to refresh an UpdatePanel from javascript](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/06/26/how-to-refresh-an-updatepanel-from-javascript.aspx)

[Refresh the UpdatePanel using JavaScript Code](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyzhao/archive/2008/04/26/refresh-the-updatepanel-using-javascript-code.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Update Updatepanel with JS

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function UpdPanelUpdate(value)
{
   var obj = document.getElementById("<%= txt.ClientID %>");
   obj.value=value;
   __doPostBack("<%= btn.ClientID %>","");
}
</script>
```